# Why does my sheet open before my data is set?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm opening my app by clicking on some URL.

I don't understand why this code makes it crash after calling the network:

```
struct MyApp: App {
    @State var openSheet = false  
    @State var dataToSend: [CustomClass]!
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            TabView {
                HomeView()
                SearchView()
                SettingsView()
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $openSheet) {
                MyView(data: dataToSend)
            }
            .onOpenURL { url in
                ApiCall.getData(from: url) { dataFromApi in
                    self.dataToSend = dataFromApi
                    self.openSheet = true
                }
            }
    }
}
```

It says "dataToSend was found nil"

But if I do this:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
    self.openSheet = true
}
```

There's no crash.

It's curious because I set the `dataFromApi` value BEFORE setting `openSheet` to true. So it's supposed to open MyView only AFTER `dataFromApi` is set, so it can't be nil...

EDIT:
If I do this:

```
@State var data: [HDJ] = []
```

There is no crashing anymore, but it is sending an empty value.

So the problem seems to be that the sheet opens before the value is set.

Comment: API call is asynchronous, but you force-unwrap optional variable, so got crash. Do not use force-unwrap, unwrap conditionally.

Comment: @Asperi look my update, the problem is not about optional value

Comment: The problem (crash) **is** about optional value. Never declare an array in a SwiftUI scene or view as implicit unwrapped optional. Don't. Declare it as non-optional empty array. SwiftUI relies much more on non-optionals than Objective-C derived UIKit. As already mentioned your API works asynchronously, the data is received later

Comment: @vadian fine, but as said in my edit, if I use an empty array, it is sending this empty array. So ok it's no crashing anymore, but it is still opening sheet BEFORE my data is set

Comment: Then there is a timing issue in the `getData` call as `openSheet` is set to `true` in the closure

Comment: use the `.sheet(item:)` vs `.sheet(isPresented)`. Change this `@State var dataToSend: [CustomClass]!` to `@State var dataToSend: [CustomClass]?`

Comment: Agree with the above comment. `sheet(item:)` is the right way to address this issue.

Comment: @loremipsum sorry guys, how to use sheet(item:) ? I've never seen this function

Comment: I added an answer `.sheet(item:)` only works with `Identifiable` objects, an array is not `Identifiable`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
.sheet(item: $dataToSend) { item in
    MyView(data: item)
}
.onOpenURL { url in
    ApiCall.getData(from: url) { dataFromApi in
        self.dataToSend = dataFromApi
    }
}
```

Sheet is now opened as soon as "dataToSend" is set, and this is perfect

Answer (score 0):

I can't find the answer(I swear it was on SO somewhere) but .sheet(isPresented) is basically preloaded. Ie the first time your main view appears it passes data into the .sheet(ie your 'dataToSend') in its state it is at the moment your main view has appeared.